# Where can I find the css for different styles in react-quill

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, quill, react-quill

I am new to UI, so please bear with me. I am trying to use react-quill and in it I can see that when we make a custom toolbar we have to use different style for different buttons. One of those styles for example is "ql-bold".

An example codepen : https://codepen.io/alexkrolick/pen/xgyOXQ?editors=0010

```
 <button className="ql-bold" />
 <button className="ql-italic" />
 <select className="ql-color">
```

I want to import this style in my project without using react-quill component. One option that I have currently is to inspect these styles and copy those styles in my project but since there are to many different styles apart from "ql-bold" I don't want to go down that path.
How should I go about?

Comment: Do you want to dynamically change the theme?

Comment: @AurelioLIMAFERREIRA I want to be able to use the styles provided by quill in my project. Styles like "ql-italic" and "ql-bold". For that purpose what kind of import do I have to do?

Comment: these class are not used for style, if you want to custom your style change this : 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.7/quill.bubble.css